# How to pass input to python getpass when executing the script

Tags: python, automation

There is a READ-ONLY python script *inputpass.py*

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import getpass
p = getpass.getpass()
if p == 'test':
    print("WORKING")
else:
    print('NOT WORKING')
```

For automation I want to pass all input when running the python script. Is there a way possible?
something like `echo 'test' | python3 inputpass.py`

Comment: it may read directly from keyboard instead of `stdin` and this can make problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution using `expect`. Ref https://phoenixnap.com/kb/linux-expect for more details.

```
expect -c 'spawn python3 inputpass.py; expect "prompt"; send "test\r"; interact'
```

Output:

```
spawn python3 inputpass.py
prompt
WORKING
```

Answer (score 0):

I assumed your read-only password prompt actually has a prompt of "prompt".
I used [pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) to run your script with another python script. (All code was run to verify function.)

inputpass.py

```
import getpass
p = getpass.getpass("prompt")
if p == "test":
    print("WORKING")
else:
    print("NOT WORKING")
```

run.py

```
import pexpect

child = pexpect.spawn("python -u inputpass.py")
child.expect("prompt")
child.sendline("test")
while not child.eof():
    print(child.readline().decode(), end="")
child.terminate()
```

You can run it with:

```
pip install pexpect
python run.py
```

the output is:

```
$ python run.py

WORKING
```